# MySQL- How to get dynamic table name in sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario is like this:

- list of different types of insurance    [ID, name, desc]
- each insurance has a different unique table.    [ID, user_id, ]

I want to query to show the columns of Insurance like [ID, Name, DESC] and a new column to show whether this user has applied for this insurance or not. No need to worry for the user part.

Just guide me how can I sub-query with dynamic table name.

I tried making a setup table where each insurance maps to its table name. But in my sub query how to do that.

If user has applied then show 1 otherwise 0.

```
SELECT   i1.ID, 
     i1.name, 
     i1.desc, 
     IF(true, 1, 0) AS EXIST
    #(SELECT t1.c_user_id FROM @tbl_name t1 WHERE t1.id = '101')
FROM app_fd_pdrm_insur_type i1;
```

Please, guide me what to replace with true.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do i attach sample data?

Comment: How do you identify, if user is applied or not?

Comment: @JimMacaulay if the commented row where t1.id = currentuser_id   has a record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT i1.ID, i1.name, i1.desc, IF( EXISTS(SELECT t1.c_user_id FROM @tbl_name t1 WHERE t1.id = '101'), 1, 0) as Exists FROM app_fd_pdrm_insur_type i1;
```

Comment: Explain @tbl_name

Comment: @tbl_name is dynamic.

Comment: That is the question how to make it dynamic. Show your logic

Comment: which programming language are you using? If it is C#, then you can add table name by parameter using mysql command object

Comment: its database MySQL. ofcourse, if programming language then quite flexible already.

Comment: You have asked to guide you, what to replace with true. For this I have answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215769/discussion-between-shahbaz-ahmad-and-awais-ahmad).